# Most efficient way to construct variable names by index in Golang for loop

Tags: for-loop, go

New to Golang. If I want to construct 10 different variables using a forloop by the index (example below), what is the most efficient way to concatenate the index and the variable name? Obviously the following approach is incorrect.

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    user + i:= CreateUser("user_num_" + i)
    user + i + bytes, _ := json.Marshal(&user + i)
}
```

Comment: You can't. Identifiers are defined at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you want a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)?

Comment: @Adrian I am looking for a solution that passes compilation obv. Why can we not do something like this at compile time?

Comment: The for loop is executed at runtime. You can't use a for loop to name variables, because variables names are set at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7):

```
users := make([]User, 10)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    users[i] = CreateUser(fmt.Sprintf("user_num_%d", i))
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(users[i])
    // TODO: handle err
    fmt.Printf("OK: user[%d] = %s\n", i, string(bytes))
}
```

Like their underlying [array](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6) structure, slices allow you to store an ordered sequence of items and refer to them by their index.